# How to make a flowing aura effect

Tags: particles, effects

Is there a way to make an aura effect like the picture shown below?
I just want it to be able to (flow around the object/This is not shown in the image below.) and (flow away from the object/Is shown in the image below).

[image]
http://img.photobucket.com/albums/1103/lionheart/Yamazakiaura.jpg

If i need to be more specific please tell me what about.

Comment: I think you will need to show us sample animation how this aura is working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **Particle System** and a **Force Field**.

[image]

The particle system is on the sphere (or your object). You can see the settings on the left panel. I added more particles so the effect is more visible (Emission/Number : 25,000). I increased the initial speed of the particles (Velocity/Normal : 2). I disabled the gravity so the particles wont fall (Field weights/Gravity : 0).

Then i added a Turbulence Force Field (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>/Force Field/Turbulence). The settings can be seen on the right panel. I increased Strength and Flow. The more you increase Flow, the more you will get the "tentacles" effect. To find the settings that works best for you, you can play the animation with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then play with the settings.

To go further, you can try different force fields (ie, a Wind turned up so the particles will go up). You can also animate the location/rotation of the force field. You can even mix many different force fields.

Comment: You can try turning these particles into hair for linked dynamic effects like the lightning in the OP .

Comment: the particles don't have as much of a trailing effect like in the picture